# Easy way to search a string for strings

Tags: string, search, c#-2.0

I'm trying to find the easiest way to search a `string` for an array of possible `string`s.  I know the easy way to do this for characters is to use `myString.IndexOfAny(charArray)`.  But how what if I'd like to search my `string` for `string`s and not just characters?  Are there any .net tricks or methods that make this easier?

Basically, I'd like to do something like this:

```
string myName = "rahkim";
string[] names = new string[] {"joe","bob","chris"};

if(myName.IndexOfAny(names) >= 0)
{
      //success code//
}
```

I know there are ways to do this with loops, etc.  But I was hoping for something inherent in the framework.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate. Seems he wants to search for a substring within each string in the array.

Comment: @Samuel, where do you get that from, he clearly has myName and search through an array of "names"?

Comment: @TStamper: From IndexOfAny(...), unless he is horribly confused about C# string methods.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  My use of IndexOfAny in the example was probably misleading.  I was basically hoping for a "similar" type solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (also) use the `static` `IndexOf` method of the `Array` class:

```
bool hasName = Array.IndexOf(names, myName) > -1;
```

Answer (score 11):

You should define if you want to to find equal strings or search for a matching substring. Both ways are easy pre-LINQ and with LINQ.

```
string myName = "rahkim";
string[] names = new string[] { "joe", "bob", "chris" };
```

Equal Strings, LINQ

```
bool contains = names.Contains(myName);
```

Equal Strings, Pre-LINQ

```
bool contains = new List<string>(name).Contains(myName);
```

Substrings, LINQ

```
bool contains = names.Any(name => name.Contains(myName));
```

Substring, Pre-LINQ

```
bool contains = false;
foreach(string name in names)
  if (name.Contains(myName))
    contains = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for these examples.  I actually liked the "Equal Strings, Pre-LINQ" one, but it gave me an error - Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'.  Im probably missing something here...

Comment: That's because it should be:
`bool contains = new List<string>(names).Contains(myName);`

BTW, Substrings, LINQ can also be shorter: `bool contains = names.Any(myName.Contains);`

Answer (score 11):

If anyone else found this while trying to search for a .Net method like String.IndexOfAny(String[]), this is my solution:

**C#**

```
public int IndexOfAny(string test, string[] values)
{
int first = -1;
foreach (string item in values) {
    int i = test.IndexOf(item);
    if (i >= 0) {
        if (first > 0) {
            if (i < first) {
                first = i;
            }
        } else {
            first = i;
        }
    }
}
return first;
}
```

**VB**

```
Public Function IndexOfAny(test As String, values As String()) As Integer
        Dim first As Integer = -1
        For Each item As String In values
            Dim i As Integer = test.IndexOf(item)
            If i >= 0 Then
                If first > 0 Then
                    If i < first Then
                        first = i
                    End If
                Else
                    first = i
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return first
    End Function
```

You can do a LastIndexOfAny(String[]) by just switching the

```
i < first
```

to

```
i > first
```

Comment: In the 6th line, "if (i > 0)" - that should be "if (i >= 0)".

Answer (score 4):

**int IndexOfAny(String[] rgs)** would indeed be nice but it's nominally an O(n^2) operation. If, in your application, the set of strings *rgs* is large and always the same, the most efficient approach is to load them into a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure once, and then use the trie repeatedly to search for them within the unknown strings given at runtime.

Here is the relevant code, adapted from a C# trie source I found on the web, attributed to "Kerry D. Wong." In my version, each string in the trie has a "payload" of generic type *TValue*. To use this trie to simply search for substrings, the payload could always be set to *true*, as illustrated with *simple_trie*.

The other thing I changed here is that this trie automatically adapts allow for storage of arbitrary Unicode strings. The array at each node—which characterizes a trie—adjusts its base and length to accomodate the range of Unicode characters which need to be stored at that node. This allows for case-sensitive matching, for example.

The C# 3.0 initialization syntax is handy for this trie, but enabling it requires a dummy implementation of *IEnumerable* in order to compile. The CLR doesn't seem to call GetEnumerator() and I suggest that you don't try to enumerate with its result either.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;  // only used in Main()

class Program
{
    // trie with payload of type <String>
    static Trie<String> value_trie = new Trie<String>
    {
        { "rabbit", "cute" },
        { "giraffe", "tall" },
        { "ape", "smart" },
        { "hippo", "large" },
    };

    // degenerate case of a trie without payload
    static Trie<bool> simple_trie = new Trie<bool>
    {
        { "rabbit", true },
        { "giraffe", true },
        { "ape", true },
        { "hippo", true },
    };

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "Once upon a time, a rabbit met an ape in the woods.";

        // Retrieve payloads for words in the string.
        //
        // output:
        //      cute
        //      smart
        foreach (String word in value_trie.AllSubstringValues(s))
            Console.WriteLine(word);

        // Simply test a string for any of the words in the trie.
        // Note that the Any() operator ensures that the input is no longer
        // traversed once a single result is found.
        //
        // output:
        //      True
        Console.WriteLine(simple_trie.AllSubstringValues(s).Any(e=>e));

        s = "Four score and seven years ago.";
        // output:
        //      False
        Console.WriteLine(simple_trie.AllSubstringValues(s).Any(e => e));
    }
}

class TrieNode<TValue>
{
    private TrieNode<TValue>[] nodes = null;
    private TValue m_value = default(TValue);
    private Char m_base;

    public Char Base { get { return m_base; } }
    public bool IsEnd { get { return !m_value.Equals(default(TValue)); } }

    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return m_value; }
        set { m_value = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrieNode<TValue>> Nodes { get { return nodes; } }

    public TrieNode<TValue> this[char c]
    {
        get
        {
            if (nodes != null && m_base <= c && c < m_base + nodes.Length)
                return nodes[c - m_base];
            return null;
        }
    }

    public TrieNode<TValue> AddChild(char c)
    {
        if (nodes == null)
        {
            m_base = c;
            nodes = new TrieNode<TValue>[1];
        }
        else if (c >= m_base + nodes.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref nodes, c - m_base + 1);
        }
        else if (c < m_base)
        {
            Char c_new = (Char)(m_base - c);
            TrieNode<TValue>[] tmp = new TrieNode<TValue>[nodes.Length + c_new];
            nodes.CopyTo(tmp, c_new);
            m_base = c;
            nodes = tmp;
        }

        TrieNode<TValue> node = nodes[c - m_base];
        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new TrieNode<TValue>();
            nodes[c - m_base] = node;
        }
        return node;
    }
};

class Trie<TValue> : System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
    private TrieNode<TValue> _root = new TrieNode<TValue>();

    // This dummy enables C# 3.0 initialization syntax
    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void Add(String s, TValue v)
    {
        TrieNode<TValue> node = _root;
        foreach (Char c in s)
            node = node.AddChild(c);

        node.Value = v;
    }

    public bool Contains(String s)
    {
        TrieNode<TValue> node = _root;
        foreach (Char c in s)
        {
            node = node[c];
            if (node == null)
                return false;
        }
        return node.IsEnd;
    }

    public TValue Find(String s_in)
    {
        TrieNode<TValue> node = _root;
        foreach (Char c in s_in)
        {
            node = node[c];
            if (node == null)
                return default(TValue);
        }
        return node.Value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> FindAll(String s_in)
    {
        TrieNode<TValue> node = _root;
        foreach (Char c in s_in)
        {
            node = node[c];
            if (node == null)
                break;
            if (node.Value != null)
                yield return node.Value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> AllSubstringValues(String s)
    {
        int i_cur = 0;
        while (i_cur < s.Length)
        {
            TrieNode<TValue> node = _root;
            int i = i_cur;
            while (i < s.Length)
            {
                node = node[s[i]];
                if (node == null)
                    break;
                if (node.Value != null)
                    yield return node.Value;
                i++;
            }
            i_cur++;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems like it might be easier and more efficient to use Regex with String.Join("|", args) as your expression.

Comment: @user1664043 `RegEx`s are a simple approach, but the resulting complexity is sometimes not obvious or transparent. My solution, as hinted in the first line of my posting, may be more appropriate if performance is critical, because it provides transparent guarantees on time complexity.

Comment: To be precise, `IndexOfAny(String[])` is not really _O(n^2)_ but more like _O(n*m)_, with _n_ being the size of the string in which search takes place, and _m_ being the (maximum) length of the strings being searched, assuming the number of strings is small compared to both _n_ and _m_.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the right syntax:

```
if(names.Contains(myName))
{
      //success code//
}
```

Comment: I thought the OP wants to do substring matches.. or doesn't he ?

Comment: I dont get 'Contains' as an option.  I only get array methods when the intellisense pops up.

Comment: Include Linq to get the extension - see duplicate question

Comment: I dont have Linq extension.  Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (names.Contains(myName)) 
{
//success code//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a shorter code will be:

```
string url = "https://example.com/path?z=1#abc";
int indexOfAny = Math.Min(url.IndexOf("?"), url.IndexOf("#"));

// if (indexOfAny > -1) 
//    url = url.Substring(0, indexOfAny);
```